# Purpose of using set method in below code snippet

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I was going through the Spring tutorial and I found below code snippet:

```
public class EmployeeRestController {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmployeeRestController.class);

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    public void setEmployeeService(EmployeeService employeeService) {
        this.employeeService = employeeService;
    }
}
```

My Question is that Why this method is used even though the is no call of this method.:

```
public void setEmployeeService(EmployeeService employeeService) {
        this.employeeService = employeeService;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: if you have used  @Autowired then no requirement of setmethod

Comment: @SushilMittal I have the same impressions but used in the tutorial so asked this.

Comment: Why do you believe the method is not called?

Comment: @chrylis I have limited understanding about Spring. But as per my understanding, Autowired itself is sufficient for injection, so my statement was that this is not called. But possibly it would be called while startup. Please elaborate for our benefits. Thanks

Comment: `@Autowired` is an instruction that Spring reads, and it then determines how to inject the dependency. If a setter is available, it generally prefers that as it avoids having to use an additional illegal access to the field.

Comment: @chrylis thank U for giving more insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this setter method has no significance if you use spring dependency injection to set the dependency on a class property. That's what is happening to `EmployeeRestController` by using `@Autowired` annotation to employee service property `private EmployeeService employeeService;` You can also use setter level dependency injection this way

```
 @Autowired
 public void setEmployeeService(EmployeeService employeeService) {
        this.employeeService = employeeService;
    }
```

It's a good and suggested practice to use `@Autowired` on setter instead of private properties.

Comment: But usually best to use the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

if you have used @Autowired then no requirement of setmethod so refer below code:

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeRestController {
private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmployeeRestController.class);

@Autowired
private EmployeeService employeeService;
    } 

@Service
public class EmployeeService{
 }
```

Comment: That is only partially true. Thinking about unit tests, you can start up a whole spring server just to have DI at hand, or you use the setter to inject a mock for testing purposes.

Comment: agree but i have provided answer only relevant to question.